# Why input-validation-error is not working for dropdown (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

When I try to call the validation error for the following select

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Customer.MemberShipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MemberShipTypes,"Id","Name"),"Select Membership Type" ,new{@class = "form-control"})
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Customer.MemberShipTypeId)
```

the site.css contains:

```
select.input-validation-error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

and the element printed is :

```
<select class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Membership Types must be a number." data-val-required="The Membership Types field is required." id="Customer_MemberShipTypeId" name="Customer.MemberShipTypeId"><option value="">Select Membership Type</option>
<option value="1">Pays as You Go</option>
<option value="2">Monthly</option>
<option value="3">Quaterly</option>
<option value="4">Yearly</option>
</select>
```

Any idea, why the drop-down button border cannot be marked as red.

Comment: did you try to change the select.input-validation-error to input-validation-error form-control in you site.css and see whether its working ?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried using .input-validation-error form-control {
    border: 2px solid red;
}  and it did not work.